# How to setup Avo App with Google Analytics 4?

Tags: web, google-analytics-4

right now I am setting up Avo to send events tracking to Google Analytics 4 and feeling a bit confused about the process.
I have managed to send events to Avo, but nothing goes to GA4. I include a photo of how I set up the GA4 Destination for more info. Can anyone help me?

I am quite new with GA4 as well, so there might be some problems with setting up GA4 as well.

```
const initAvoApp = async () => {
  console.log('running')

  const env = () => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') return { inspector: Inspector.AvoInspectorEnv.Dev, avoEnv: AvoEnv.Dev }
    if (process.env.NEXT_APP_ENV === 'staging')
      return { inspector: Inspector.AvoInspectorEnv.Staging, avoEnv: AvoEnv.Dev }
    return { inspector: Inspector.AvoInspectorEnv.Prod, avoEnv: AvoEnv.Prod }
  }

  const inspector = new Inspector.AvoInspector({
    apiKey: 'nbhQNPWSaF9SHA1w1jhk',
    env: env().inspector,
    version: '1.0.0',
    appName: 'My App',
  })

  const customDestination = {
    logEvent: function (eventName: string, eventProperties: object) {
      window.gtag('event', eventName, eventProperties)
    },
    identify: function (userId: string) {
      // Todo: Identify user in Google Analytics
      window.gtag('event', 'identity', userId)
    },
    unidentify: function () {
      // Todo: Unidentify currently identified user in Google Analytics
      window.gtag('event', 'identity', null)
    },
    revenue: function (amount: number, eventProperties: object) {
      window.gtag('event', 'purchase', { ...eventProperties, amount })
    },
    logPage: function (screenName: string, eventProperties: object) {
      window.gtag('event', 'screen_view', {
        ...eventProperties,
        screen_name: screenName,
      })
    },
  }

  !!customDestination &&
    initAvo(
      {
        env: env().avoEnv,
        inspector: inspector,
        reportFailureAs: 'log',
      },
      [customDestination],
      customDestination,
    )
}
```

[Destination Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5h0I.png)